# Why does exiting Utop and reloading of modules not work?

Tags: ocaml, utop

When I start my utop interpreter
and then

```
say #quit;;
```

I get the answer `Error: unbound value quit`

The command

```
#Topfind.reset();;
```

doesn't recompile the ml-files, that I have changed

I always need to kill the whole terminal and start a new one, which makes work tedious.

What do I do wrong?

Comment: Are you typing `Topfind.reset ();;` at the `#` prompt, or typing `#Topfind.reset ();;`?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with the exiting of the interpreter. I had to type

```
#quit;;
```

instead of just quit;;
The command prompt is also #, so the line looks like

```
# #quit;;
```

in the end

Topfind.reset();; does still not work.

Comment: For exiting utop, also `exit 0;;`